# Make something shine in webgl & c3dl

Tags: canvas, webgl

I'm building a little starfield program using webgl and such.

Currently, my star are regular points. It looks nice from a very far distance, but pretty boring once you zoom into it.

How can I add things to make it look a bit more star-like? Like shine and shimmer and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This webgl lesson](http://learningwebgl.com/lessons/lesson09/index.html) has something that might be close to what you want. It's a rendered gif, (rotating) with the option of rendering another identical gif over it (non-rotating) to provide the "twinkle" effect. Note, it's only got 50 stars so may perform quite badly with a star field.

You can see all the lessons [here](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217).

Comment: That's perfect. I only need an effect on 1 star at a time, so it'll do. Interesting tutorials, I've been looking for something like them!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called particle effects

http://www.mrspeaker.net/dev/parcycle/

Comment: Also lookup for bloom effects